# Pushing Values into Array using Slice or Push still returning Undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to simply push values into an array, and am struggling to make any progress here. I'm trying to create a simple function where you enter a string of numbers and it returns dashes in-between each odd number - so:

```
oddDash(11146); // should return 1-1-146
oddDash(24662); // should return 24662
oddDash(9899); // should return 989-9
```

Having read around, it seems that the array needs to be initialised first to prevent undefined instances, but it pushes undefined into each array value anyway.

Here's my code:

```
function oddDash(n) { // e.g. var n = 11146;

    var arr = (""+n).split(""); // ["1", "1", "1", "4", "6"]
    var result = []; // initialisation

    result = arr.map(function(c,i,a) {
        if (c % 2 != 0 && a[i+1] % 2 != 0) { // if this & next values are odd
            result.push(c);
            result.push('-');
        } else {
            result.push(c);
        }
    }); // should return ["1", "-", "1", "-", "1", "-", "4", "6"]
}
```

So my main questions are: why is undefined being pushed into each array value? And why aren't any dashes being pushed in either?

I've retried using slice which also returns undefined, and using an ordinary for loop which doesn't do anything.

Out of curiosity, could someone explain why the below works:

```
// NO ERROR
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var result = arr.map(function(c,i,a) {
    console.log(c);
});
```

But the three below don't work:

```
// FAILS
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var result = arr.map(function(c,i,a) {
    result.slice(c);
});

// FAILS
why doesht this work>?
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var result = arr.map(function(c,i,a) {
    result.push(c);
});

// DOES NOTHING
function oddDash(n) { // e.g. var n = 11146;

    var arr = (""+n).split(""); // ["1", "1", "1", "4", "6"]
    var result = []; // initialisation

    for (k = 0; k > arr.length; k++) {

        if (arr[k] % 2 != 0 && arr[k+1] % 2 != 0) {
            result.push(arr[k]);
            result.push('-');
        } else {
            result.push(arr[k]);
        }

    }
}
```

Aren't the principles the same here? I feel like there's something that I'm not understanding. Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function iterates over a collection, and returns a new collection where each element is replaced with its corresponding return value. This means that if you don't return anything in your callback function, the array will be filled with `undefined` as values.

For example:

```
// new array will equal [2,3,4]
const array = [1,2,3].map(element => element + 1);

// but... new array will equal [undefined, undefined, undefined]
const array = [1,2,3].map(element => console.log(element));
```

Even though you push values to the new array, you're assigning the value of the mapped array to it, which in turn is filled with `undefined` as values, so that's the final value of your array.
So instead, try returning the values you want instead of pushing them to the new array.

If you want to remove specific elements you should use the `filter` function, and if you want to combine `map` and `filter`, you should check out the `reduce` function.